# Curried function in scala

Tags: scala, currying

I have a definition of next methods:

```
def add1(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y

def add2(x: Int)(y: Int) = x + y
```

the second one is curried version of first one. Then if I want to partially apply second function I have to write `val res2 = add2(2) _`. Everything is fine. Next I want `add1` function to be curried. I write

```
val curriedAdd = (add1 _).curried
```

Am I right that curriedAdd is similiar to `add2`?
But when I try to partially apply `curriedAdd` in a such way `val resCurried = curriedAdd(4) _` I get a compilation error. Then I fix it to

```
val resCurried = curriedAdd(4)
```

Why the result of a `Functions.curried` differs from curried version of add function(from `add2`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly `curriedAdd` is same as `add2 _` and not `add2`. add2 is just a method.

```
scala> curriedAdd
res52: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>

scala> add2 _
res53: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>
```

About the second question. I think the below is the reason. Doing

```
scala> val i = curriedAdd(23)
i: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> i _
res54: () => Int => Int = <function0>

scala> curriedAdd(23) _
<console>:10: error: _ must follow method; cannot follow Int => Int
              curriedAdd(23) _
```

`curriedAdd(23) _` does not work. Lets look at scala manual (§6.7)-

> The expression e _ is well-formed if e is of method type or if e is a
>   call-by-name parameter. If e is a method with parameters, e _
>   represents e converted to a function type by eta expansion (§6.26.5).
>   If e is a parameterless method or call-by-name parameter of type =>T ,
>   e _ represents the function of type () => T , which evaluates e when
>   it is applied to the empty parameterlist ().

Remember it only evaluates if it is a *method* or *call-by-name* parameter. In  `curriedAdd(23) _`, it does not evaluate curriedAdd(23) but checks if it is a method or call-by-name. It is not a method nor a *call-by-name* parameter.

It is not *by-name* because *by-name* is the property of variable. Above you get a *by-name* parameter after evaluating `curriedAdd(23)` but `curriedAdd(23)` in itself is not a *by-name* variable. Hence the error (Ideally the compiler should have coverted it). Note that the below works:

```
scala> curriedAdd(23)
res80: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> res80 _
res81: () => Int => Int = <function0>
```

The above works because `res80 _`, here you are applying `_` to a *call-by-name* parameter and hence does the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, let's take a look at the REPL.

First we define the two functions as you did.

```
scala> def add1(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
add1: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> def add2(x: Int)(y: Int) = x + y
add2: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int
```

We have defined two functions. The first one expects two parameters in one parameterlist. The second one expects two parameters, each one in an own parameterlist. The result type is the same.

Let's move on.

```
scala> val curriedAdd = (add1 _).curried
curriedAdd: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>
```

You just created a partial applied function, that expects **one** parameter and returns a partial applied function of type `Int => Int`. This is not as similar to `add2` as you expect it to be.

To achieve the same for `add2`, you would need to call

```
scala> val curriedAdd2 = add2 _
curriedAdd2: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. `curriedAdd(4) _` does not work but `val i = curriedAdd(4); i _` works.

Comment: The question was: "Why the resultof a Functions.curried differs from curried version of add function(from add2)?"
I guess i pointed out the differences.