# Function currying in scala

Tags: scala

I’m learning scala and read this concept called ‘currying’. I know it is used to divide the parameters in a function and pass them one by one. So from what I understood I tried creating a simple basic currying function below:

```
def add_num(a:Int,b:Int)(c:Int):Int={a+b+c}
add_num(10,20)
add_num(10)
```

But it gives me an error when I call the function with values 10 and 20. What i understood is it will remember the values and then I can pass the third value as 10 separately. I’m unable to understand this concept. Can someone help me in understanding this concept in most basic terms.

Error is missing argument list for method add_num. Unsupplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is executed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curried function in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398574/curried-function-in-scala)

Comment: Try `val almost = add_num(10,20) _` followed by `almost(7)`.

Comment: I tried this val f = add_num(10,20)(_) f(10) and it gave me the result as 40. But I don’t understand why do I have to use a placeholder and then passing its value, what is the benefit of currying if I still have to use it like this.

Comment: The benefit is that you now have the partially applied function as a separate object in a variable and can give that to some other part of your application that does not need to know about the first two parameters. Consider that your function calls an API. The part of your application that sets up credentials could curry a function to pass in the API access key. The rest of the application does then not need to care about that anymore.

Comment: @VyomVerma The point of currying is not to apply all the arguments at once, it's to be able to pass `almost` to other places in your program like `Thilo` said. If you want to give all arguments at once, you can still use `add_num(10,20)(7)`!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A curried function is applied to multiple argument lists, instead of just
one. An example of a non-curried function, which adds two `Int` parameters, `x` and `y`:

```scala
scala> def plainOldSum(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
plainOldSum: (x: Int, y: Int)Int
scala> plainOldSum(1, 2)
res4: Int = 3
```

A similar function that’s curried:

```scala
scala> def curriedSum(x: Int)(y: Int) = x + y
curriedSum: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int
scala> curriedSum(1)(2)
res5: Int = 3
```

What's happening here is that when you invoke `curriedSum`, you actually
get two traditional function invocations back-to-back. The first function
invocation takes a single `Int` parameter named `x`, and returns a function
value for the second function. This second function takes the `Int` parameter
`y`.

Here's a function named `first` that does in spirit what the first traditional
function invocation of `curriedSum` would do:

```scala
scala> def first(x: Int) = (y: Int) => x + y
first: (x: Int)Int => Int
```

Applying the `first` function to `1`—in other words, invoking the `first` function
and passing in `1`—yields the `second` function:

```scala
scala> val second = first(1)
second: Int => Int = <function1>
```

Applying the `second` function to `2` yields the result:

```scala
scala> second(2)
res6: Int = 3
```

These `first` and `second` functions are just an illustration of the currying
process. They are not directly connected to the `curriedSum` function. Nevertheless,
there is a way to get an actual reference to `curriedSum`'s "second"
function. You can use the placeholder notation to use `curriedSum` in a partially
applied function expression, like this:

```scala
scala> val onePlus = curriedSum(1)_
onePlus: Int => Int = <function1>
```

The underscore in `curriedSum(1)_` is a placeholder for the second parameter
`list.2` The result is a reference to a function which, when invoked, adds one
to its sole `Int` argument and returns the result:

```scala
scala> onePlus(2)
res7: Int = 3
```

And here's how you'd get a function that adds two to its sole `Int` argument:

```scala
scala> val twoPlus = curriedSum(2)_
twoPlus: Int => Int = <function1>
scala> twoPlus(2)
res8: Int = 4
```

Comment: This is a really clear explanation, and an exceptional first post. The Stack Overflow community is lucky to have you as a contributor.