# What Does a Variable Defined before a Scala Function Mean?

Tags: scala, object, templates, generics, context-bound

Learning Scala from the Scala for Data Science book and the companion Github repo, here I am particularly talking about [this function](https://github.com/pbugnion/s4ds/blob/master/chap02/HWData.scala#L20), copied below for reference.

```scala
    def fromList[T: ClassTag](index: Int, converter: String => T): DenseVector[T] =
      DenseVector.tabulate(lines.size) { row => converter(splitLines(row)(index)) }
```

What does the `DenseVector.tabulate(lines.size)` mean between the `=` sign and the function body definition? New to scala (with background from python and C++), so cannot figure out if that `DenseVector.tabulate(lines.size)` is a local variable of the function being defined (when it should be declared inside the definition) or something else? It cannot be the return type, from what I understand of scala syntax.

Also, is the `ClassTag` equivalent to template in C++?

To help you answer the question,

- `splitLines` has type `scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Array[String]]`
- `lines.size` is an unsigned int (obvious, but still making it clear)

Comment: `T: ClassTag` means runtime information of type T is passed along the function. For more info https://stackoverflow.com/q/40202504/757071.

Comment: `DenseVector.tabulate` is a curried function that creates a DenseVector of a particular size and applies a function to each value. For more about currying: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62448617/757071

Comment: See this also for `ClassTag`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34495711/757071

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DenseVector.tabulate` is a factory function (defined on the companion object of `DenseVector`) that has two parameter lists with one parameter each (so altogether, it takes two explicit parameters: `size: Int` and a function `f: Int => V`).

You can find its definition [here](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/dc3d837724e07238631eddc3035f7f3ed357d61b/math/src/main/scala/breeze/linalg/DenseVector.scala#L293) (as part of the breeze library).

In (pseudo-)C++ (ignoring the `ClassTag`), the corresponding declaration would probably look something like this:

```
template<classname V>
class DenseVector {
public:
    // ... other class members

    template<classname V>
    static DenseVector<V> tabulate(int size, std::function<V(int)> f);
};
```

and then `fromList` would probably look something like this:

```
template<classname T>
static DenseVector<T> fromList(int index, std::function<T(std::string)> converter) {
    return DenseVector::tabulate(lines.size, [&converter](int row){
        return converter(splitLines(row)[index]);
    });
}
```

Comment: P.S.: the typesystem of scala is fundamentally different from C++, so the following is far from correct, but: if you want to focus on other aspects of your learning path for a while and postpone learning about implict context bounds until later, you can think of `[T: ClassTag]` as somewhat similar to `template<classname T> requires ClassTag<T>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, how much of the language I need to learn before daring to jump in to start delivering (reading or writing) production code is always a dilemma, and seems scala got a lot of ground to cover.

Answer (score 2):

Your example uses several syntactic sugars.

It's the equivalent of the following which might be easier to read when starting:

```scala
def fromList[T](index: Int, converter: String => T)(implicit classtag: ClassTag[T]): DenseVector[T] = {
  def rowConverter(row: ???): ??? = {  
    converter(splitLines(row)(index))
  }
  DenseVector.tabulate(lines.size)(row => rowConverter(row))
}
```

Notice that:

- the whole second line (in your original code) is the body of the method
- `tabulate` is a method taking two sets of parameters
- the second set of parameters of `tabulate` is a single parameter which is a "lambda" function
- the `ClassTag` thing is called "context bound", it's a way to say the method needs an implicit value of the given type parameterized with the other type. `Classtag` itself is a way to preserve info on the type at runtime (which would be lost due to "type erasure in the JVM).